# Rest framework and URL patterns

Tags: python, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I'm learning Django + Rest Framework and trying to make simple app but I'm confused with URL patterns. It's just a blog with posts, votes and comments. The thing I want to make is to be able to send requests to that kind of url pattern to leave a comment `<post_id>/addcomment`. And I only have 404 with that. I can do it another way that is much more simple, for example just send post id in request data, but I'm learning and wanna know how to do what I want to.
I tried to override create method of my viewset. Tried to get post_id from url by serializer, maybe that's not even possible. Then I found action decorators, I don't know should I use it here and why they are not working.

**models**

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET("deleted"))
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
    added_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

**serializer**

```
class CommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_user')
    post = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_post')

    def get_user(self):
        request = self.context.get('request')
        return request.user

    # here I tried to get post_id from context but it doesn't work
    # def get_post(self):
    #     post_id = self.context.get('post_id')
    #     post = Post.objects.filter(id=post_id)[0]
    #     return post

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('body', 'post', 'user')
```

**views**

```
class CommentViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = CommentSerializer
    model = Comment

    @action(detail=True, methods=['post'])
    def addcomment(self, request, post_id=None):
        if post_id:
            post = Post.objects.filter(post=post_id)[0]
            comment = Comment.objects.create(user=request.user, post=post, body=request.data.get('body'))
            comment.save()
            return Response({"detail": "You've left the comment!"}, status=HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            return Response(status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

**urls**

```
path(r'^{post_id}/addcomment/$', views.CommentViewSet.as_view({"post": "addcomment"}), name='add-comment')
```

I also don't know how should I declare url pattern while using action decorator. Should I use `router.register` or just another `path` in urlpatterns list? In the docs I only found example pattern and that line `views.CommentViewSet.as_view({"post": "addcomment"})` I found here on StackOverflow.
I send post requests to `blog/1/addcomment` and the response is 404. What I'm missing here so server can't recognize URL?

Answer (score 0):

Well, after a lot of tryings I thought maybe I have something wrong with migrations and after I tried to make it finally Django gave me a warning about using url patterns. Seems like starting from some version I need to use `re_path` instead of regular `path` to use named primary keys (maybe I'm mistaken with terms but the thing was with `?P<...>` in pattern).
So now my url looks like `re_path(r'(?P<post_id>\d+)/addcomment/', views.CommentViewSet.as_view({'post': 'addcomment'}), name='add-comment')`. And it works perfectly.